# Spell checking not working in Aptana

Tags: spell-checking, aptana3

I have enabled spell checking, but neither HunSpell nor the default spelling engine don't seem to be doing any work - I have some intentionally misspelled words in my document, but no reaction on the part of Aptana.

According to **General/Editors/Annotions** settings Aptana should use a red squiggly line - it doesn't.

I've looked at **General/Editors/Text Editors/Spelling** options - Hunspell has been provided with the path to the dictionary files.

Nothing worth mentioning in **Aptana Studio/Spelling** options.

Have I missed something?